# Selenium, Python3, コンボボックスの現在の値の取得方法

Tags: python, python3, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = Chrome(options=options, 
executable_path='.\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://soundoftext.com/')

elem_t = driver.find_element_by_class_name("field__textarea")
elem_t.send_keys('こんにちは')

elem_c = driver.find_element_by_class_name("field__select")
elem_c_s = Select(elem_c)
elem_c_s.select_by_value("ja-JP")

a = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="app"]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/select').text
print(a)
```

とすると、

```
Afrikaans
Albanian
Arabic
Armenian
Bengali (Bangladesh)
Bengali (India)
```

…と出力されますが，現在選択されているコンボボックスの値を取得するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('field__select')[0].value;")
```

で解決

Answer (score 1):

Select を取得しているのですから以下のメソッドで選択されているoption要素がすべて取得できます。

- [Select#all_selected_options](https://www.seleniumqref.com/api/python/element_infoget/Python_all_selected_options.html)

単一選択なら以下のようにすればよいのでないでしょうか？

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = Chrome(options=options, 
executable_path='.\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://soundoftext.com/')

elem_t = driver.find_element_by_class_name("field__textarea")
elem_t.send_keys('こんにちは')

elem_c = driver.find_element_by_class_name("field__select")
elem_c_s = Select(elem_c)
elem_c_s.select_by_value("ja-JP")

print(elem_c_s.all_selected_options[0].text)

driver.quit()
```